# $_FILES php, i don't recive any file or information

Tags: php, html

i'm working to an image uploader, but i don't recive any file or information from the html form.
So, this is the html code:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <form action="pages/post/upload.php" method="post">
                <input type="file" name="userfile" required/>
                <input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php code

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/pino/Scrivania/Prova/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

print_r($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
print_r($uploadfile);
print_r($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} 

else {
    echo "Invalid File!\n";
}

echo 'Any information to debug:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
?>
```

I trid to print any information of the $_FILES array but i don't recive any information.

There are specific information to declare or import into the sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in `<form>` tag

**enctype='multipart/form-data'** - is an encoding type that allows files to be sent through a POST. means that no characters will be encoded. that is why this type is used while uploading files to server.

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <form action="pages/post/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="userfile" required/>
                <input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` add this on first line of php code and give me that output. Check array coming or not. @mastrobirraio

Comment: Ok it work but not fully.

Comment: I recive online this
`Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_20170318_072135.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)`

Comment: ok, now its may be not related to $_FILES now its something else which you missing.

Comment: your array seems [tmp_name] is empty so file will not be uploaded correctly.

Comment: It's better to make another question

Comment: Thanks and glad to help you... :)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I can't create another question because it said that i can post after 90 minutes from the last question.. So i must wait...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011818/files-i-dont-recive-all-the-information-from-the-form

Comment: This is the link for the new question