# $_FILES i don't recive all the information from the form

Tags: php

i get an image from a php form, but i don't recive all the information from the form.
The code is below:

```
<form action="pages/post/upload.php" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Invia"/>
</form>
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/pino/Scrivania/Prova/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

print_r($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
print_r($uploadfile);
print_r($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} 

else {
    echo "Possibile attacco tramite file upload!\n";
}

echo 'Alcune informazioni di debug:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

When i print the content of the file with `print_R($_FILES);` i recive the follow:

```
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => IMG_20170318_072135.jpg
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 1
        [size] => 0
    )
```

)

Comment: close your <form>-Tag

Comment: It is close, there is a copy error

Answer (score 0):

Your file has exceed the size limit (source:http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Comment: Where i can find this file?

Comment: @mastrobirraio see this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your array seems that your `$_FILES` return `[error] => 1` so its related to file upload size.

1. You need to check file upload size. Check file size with `phpinfo()`.
2. If `upload_max_filesize` less then your uploaded file size then change the file size to your image file size.
3. If `upload_max_filesize` is proper then need to check `post_max_size` variable in `php.ini` file

**For e.g:**

```
upload_max_filesize = 7M
```

**Note:**

- If you are working on `localhost` then `php.ini` file exist in `wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`.
- Also, you can write `phpinfo()` in any of your php file and run it to check server configuration.

Comment: Hope above answer will surely help you. Let me know if anything. @mastrobirraio